# How do I import modules in boost::python embedded python code?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm using boost::python to embed some python code into an app. I was able to get print statements or other expressions to be evaluated properly, but when I try to import modules, it is not importing and application is exiting. Further the globals() function call in the embedded code gives a runtime error too.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace boost::python::api;

int main(void) {
    Py_Initialize();
    object main_module = import("__main__");
    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    main_namespace["urllib2"] = import("urllib2");

    object ignored = exec(
            "print 'time'\n", main_namespace);
}
```

Here, I've tried to import urllib2 using the boost import function, this compiles and runs properly, but with the following exec statement, it gives an error.

```
    object ignored = exec(
            "print urllib2\n"
            "print 'time'\n", main_namespace);
```

Or when I remove the boost import function and do the import from within the embedded code also, it gives an error. I tried using a try: except: block but that doesn't work either. Is this because the C++ app isn't able to find the location of the urllib2 py module or something? Is there a way to set the path of the module before trying to import?

This is being built only for internal use, so some hard coding of the paths is acceptable.

*Edit: More info:* 
This is what happens. I did a try .. catch and called the PyErr_Print() when ever there is an exception, and got this as error all the time when there are module imports or even function calls. Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anyone think of any reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That didn't help, but I found a different solution to my problem. My current code looks like this:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace boost::python::api;

int main(void) {
        Py_Initialize();
        boost::python::object http = boost::python::import("urllib2");

        try
        {
                boost::python::object response = http.attr("urlopen")("http://www.google.com");
                boost::python::object read = response.attr("read")();
                std::string strResponse = boost::python::extract<string>(read);
                cout << strResponse << endl;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
                PyErr_Print();
                PyErr_Clear();
        }
}
```

Anyways, thanks for the answer Jonas

Comment: Glad you got your code working. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Oh. I was totally sick of the C++ sockets libraries. They need time to understand, and since I'm not a computers student, I take longer to understand. So I created something that feels like an asynchronous urllib++ with the python urllib2 in the back. :D I know it sounds crazy. But I have an extremely convenient solution now!

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already, you need to

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/user/whatever")
```

That took care of my problems a couple of years ago when embedding boost::python (Python v2.5).

Edit:

Poked around in old code. Perhaps this does the trick:

```
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
Py_InitializeEx(0);
```

Sounds unsure that you should really need the `Py_SetProgramName()`, but I faintly remember some fishy business there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and really for the delay in trying it and telling you, Jonas.

I tried it but this wasn't helping. I'm not even able to to get the program to run if it has this single statement "print globals()\n". I tried the same code on windows and linux, and same response everywhere.

I'm using Boost 1.39.0

Comment: I was having a mysterious segmentation fault when importing certain libraries (such as gzip or numpy).

Then this hack solves the problem like a charm:
`Py_SetProgramName("");`
`Py_InitializeEx(0);`

Thanks @Jonas

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you, i e a very simple example resulting in the TypeError, and found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215752/python-embedded-in-cpp-how-to-get-data-back-to-cpp/215772), which was to supply the namespace twice, both as global and local.