# boost python - embedding in c++ and passing variables

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

**Introduction**

I'm trying to do a simple thing - in theory, but so far not in practise. I have C++ console application, with embedded python script. It has to pass some variables inside python, do calculation, and send it back.

**Example code**

my cpp file look like this (based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216224/5489190) answer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;

    Py_Initialize();
    try
    {
        object module = import("__main__");
        object name_space = module.attr("__dict__");
        exec_file("Script.py", name_space, name_space);

        object MyFunc = name_space["MyFunc"];
        object result = MyFunc(a,b);

        int sum = extract<int>(result["sum"]);
        std::cout << sum;
    }
    catch (error_already_set)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();
}
```

My Script.py file is very simple

```
def MyFunc(a,b):
    result = a+b
    return result
```

**The Issue**

I expected, that python will accept two variables, sum it, and let extract it back do my C++. Then C++ print the results. However it ends with following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I think that MyFunc(a,b) is not correct call, however I can't figure why. Should I pass variables in other way? If yes, pleas explain me how to do this.

Comment: I think, you need `extract<int>(result)`.

Comment: Indeed, it works. It seems that I overgeneralized the code I referenced above. It's really surprising, the mistake was so elemental.