# embedding python in c++: python script not recognized

Tags: python, c++, embed

I am trying to embed python script into c++ project.
Below is what I have tried so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int
main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path"); 
    PyObject* modPath = PyBytes_FromString("C:\\Users\\naal\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\Project1\pyscripts");
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath,0, modPath);
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("myscript2");
    printf("%p\n", pModule);
    return 0;
}
```

below is the python script "myscript2.py"

```
def find_me():
    print("hey you found me")
```

The problem is, the main module is not able to find the python script i.e object pyModule is always NULL, no matter how I change python script path.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing this in another way.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {    
       std::string location = "C:\\Users\\myscript.py";     
       const char* file_location = location.c_str();    FILE* file_pointer;          
       Py_Initialize();
       file_pointer = _Py_fopen(file_location, "r");
       PyRun_SimpleFile(file_pointer, file_location);

       Py_Finalize();
       return 1;
       }
```

The above seemed to work. I still don't know why the SYSPATH idea originially mentioned in the question didn't work.